# Trouble with editing contents/message of Empty Side Cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, code-snippets

I am trying to change the default text thats in the empty side cart on WooCommerce. It just doesn't look inviting at all.

For some reason all my atempts fail, I have limited understanding of PHP but for the love of god I can't see anything wrong with me code.

**This code has been added as a PHP snippet:**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_mini_cart_empty_message', 'custom_empty_cart_message', 10 );
function custom_empty_cart_message() {
    ?>
    <div class="woocommerce-mini-cart__empty-message">
        <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/SD-logo.png" alt="Empty Cart Image">
        <p>Your cart is currently empty.</p>
        <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" class="button wc-forward">Shop Now</a>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Possible solutions that won't work include translation and gettext and replace text since I want an image and button in there. If anyone has a clue how to solve this please do reply as your help is much appreciated

Replace the default empty side cart message with an image, text and button

Comment: Have you tried this hook `wc_empty_cart_message `

Comment: @mujuonly , thanks for the reply. That didn't work :(